# How to get beans created by FactoryBean spring managed?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

The [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) can be used to programmatically create objects which might require complex instantiation logic.

However, it seems that the beans *created* by the `FactoryBean` doesn't become spring managed.  Is this interpretation correct? If so, are there any nice workarounds? A short code sample is included to illustrate my problem.

ApplicationContext:

```
<bean id="searcher" class="some.package.SearcherFactory" /> 
<bean id="service" class="some.package.Service" />
```

Factory implementation:

```
public class SearcherFactory implements FactoryBean<Searcher> {

    @Override
    public Searcher getObject() throws Exception {
        return new Searcher(); // not so complex after all ;)
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Searcher> getObjectType() {
        return Searcher.class;
    }
    .... 
}
```

Class created by the factory:

```
public class Searcher() {
      private Service service;

      @Autowired
      public void setService(Service service) {
           // never invoked
           this.service=service;
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The object created by the `FactoryBean` *are* managed by Spring, but not instantiated or configured by Spring. By using a `FactoryBean`, you take responsibility for that yourself. All injection and config must be handled by the `FactoryBean`

There is an alternative which may work better for you - use [annotation-based config instead of XML-based config](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). This means you can have complex instantiation logic in Java, whilst still using things like `@Autowired` on the objects themselves.

I tend to use annotation-style config for all non-trivial Spring apps now, it makes many things a lot easier.

Comment: +1. I've just started working with annotation based config for dealing with exactly these types of scenarios.

Comment: So, how would you solve the issue author has? Could you update an answer with appropriate java configuration?

Answer (score 33):

Here is an abstract `FactoryBean` implementation that does autowiring for you:

```
public abstract class AbstractAutowiringFactoryBean<T> extends
    AbstractFactoryBean<T> implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext){
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected final T createInstance() throws Exception{
        final T instance = doCreateInstance();
        if(instance != null){
            applicationContext
              .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
              .autowireBean(instance);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Create the bean instance.
     * 
     * @see #createInstance()
     */
    protected abstract T doCreateInstance();

}
```

Extend it, implement the `getObjectType()` and `doCreateInstance()` methods and you're up and running with autowiring.

**Note:** BeanPostProcessors are not applied, that would require additional code.

Comment: That's not a bad idea either either, improving reusability. Although I wonder why this wasn't already provided as a template by our friends over at springsource.

Answer (score 18):

What about this ?

```
<bean id="serviceFactory"
      class="some.package.SearcherFactory" />


<bean id="service"
      factory-bean="serviceFactory"
      factory-method="getObject"/>
```

... and then just inject the bean 'service' and do not care about the factory in your code

Comment: tried this one, resulted in a stacktrace with an issue, that the getObject() method does not exist. According to this link: http://goo.gl/V6NyLv a service.getObject().getObject() would be called.

Comment: The commenter doesn't mean to literally copy the above as-is. Your SearchFactory type in this case needs to implement a method like getObject() that will return an object of the desired type, or you can name that method whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

A manual way would be:

1. Inject the dependencies in the factory bean
2. set them manually on the target object.

You can also inject `ApplicationContext` in the factory bean (or get it by implementing `ApplicationContextAware`), and do `ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(bean)`

I admit both feel strange, though.

But in fact, if the logic is that simple (only instantiation), use `prototype` scope.

Comment: It works, and at least, the spring coupling can be reduced to a single factory class.

Answer (score 0):

A FactoryBean is an interface that you, as a developer, implements when writing factory classes and you want the object created by the factory class to be managed as a bean by Spring, while a BeanFactory on the other hand, represents the Spring IoC container, it contains the managed beans and provides access to retrieving them. It is part of the core of the framework which implements the base functionality of an inversion of control container.

In most cases you won't find yourself using or implementing the BeanFactory interface directly, unless you are extending the core functionality of the framework. While you would do implement the FactoryBean when you have objects that are created by Factories that needs to be managed by Spring.

In more succinct words, the BeanFactory represents the Spring container while the FactoryBean represents factory classes whose created object are picked up and registered as a bean in the container.

```
File: context.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="sha" class="MessageDigestFactoryBean">
        <property name="algorithm" value="SHA1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="md5" class="MessageDigestFactoryBean"/>

</beans>


File: Main.java

import java.security.MessageDigest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("context.xml"));
    String d1 = (String) factory.getBean("sha");
    String d2 = (String) factory.getBean("md5");
    System.out.println(d1);
    System.out.println(d2);
  }

}

class MessageDigestFactoryBean implements FactoryBean, InitializingBean {
  private static final String DEFAULT_ALGORITHM = "MD5";

  private String algorithm = DEFAULT_ALGORITHM;

  public Object getObject() throws Exception {
    return this.algorithm;
  }

  public Class getObjectType() {
    return MessageDigest.class;
  }

  public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
  }

  public void setAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
    this.algorithm = algorithm;
  }

  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    this.algorithm += " after setting";
  }
}
```