# Spring Dependency injection with factory(dynamic value)

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to spring.

I've a rulefactory, which would return an instance from a static method
based on the type value

Now i'll get the type from the main methods, argument.

Now i would like to pass the argument type to the factory method getInstance
type argument.

how to do that.

/* Factory class, getInstance will return a subtype of RuleEvaluation, for simplicity, i've not
provided the Implementation class for SingleRuleEvaluation and MassRuleEvaluation. Basically both the classes implements RuleEvaluation */

```
public class RuleEvalFactory {


    public static RuleEvaluation getInstance(String type) {
        if (type != null && type.equals("Single")) {
            return new SingleRuleEvaluation();
        } else if (type != null &&  type.equals("mass")) {
            return new MassRuleEvaluation();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

/* My Main class , i need to get an instance of the RuleEvaluation here based on the type(dyamic)
dont know how to do it.
 */

```
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-All-Module.xml");
        String type = args[0];
            /* i want to pass the above type String to the factory method and get the instance how to do that */ 

        RuleEvaluation re = (HarmonyService) context.getBean("rulefactory") ;
    }

}
```

/* my Spring xml configuration file */

```
Spring xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="instanceMethodFactory" class="test.factory.RuleEvalFactory"> </bean>

          <!-- i dont know how to pass the dynamic type from the Myapp main
method into this constructory argument -->

      <bean id="rulefactory" factory-bean="instanceMethodFactory" factory-method="getInstance">
        <constructor-arg index="0"> </constructor-arg>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

Please give the code in Spring xml and Myapp main method how to inject the type into the factory method's getInstance.

Regards,
Raghu

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get beans created by FactoryBean spring managed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970297/how-to-get-beans-created-by-factorybean-spring-managed)

Comment: The above link, doesnt answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify in the bean the constructor argument,

```
<bean id="myBean" class="A" scope="prototype">
  <constructor-arg value="0"/> <!-- dummy value --> 
</bean>
```

And then pass the value to bean factory,

```
getBean("myBean", argument);
```